# PHP - How can I get the 'URL' value of a php page which using cURL script?

Tags: php, url, curl, get

I have 2 php files: "1.php" & "2.php".

"1.php" with content like this:

```
<?PHP
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

when I go to http://domain.com/1.php -> it will return content of www.google.com

The question is:
How can I get the URL which is the "www.google.com" of "1.php" using "2.php"?

(I want when I go to "http://domain.com/2.php" it would show "www.google.com" text.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two files, you can use three: a configuration file, which will contain the URL, and two others that will use this URL in two different ways.

For example (to use your filenames):

conf.php (configutation file):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.fr/";
```

1.php (your code):

```
<?php
//Include conf file
require 'conf.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
```

2.php (your code again):

```
<?php
//Include conf file
require 'conf.php';

echo $url;
```

Some possible improvements: use less generic names and an array (instead `$url` we can consider for example `$conf['url']`)